# Save responses to a file via requests

Tags: python, python-requests

In my situation, I have only 1 iteration of response:

```
import requests

url = "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db"
response = requests.get(url)


for i in response:
    with open('/Path/To/File/test_file({0}).db'.format(i+1), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

The problem is that I receive error message:

```
TypeError: can't concat int to bytes
```

I need to save a file to the specific folder every iteration and give a different name.

Comment: are you working on `.db` file using `with open`???

Comment: Only that I do is download a file, and save him to a specific folder, this is the example file.

Comment: You can't iterate over 'response' and expect i to be numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
count = 0
with open('/Path/To/File/test_file({0}).db'.format(count+1), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
    count +=1
```

You are getting the error because the request is a byte object.

Comment: Hi again, can you tell me please where is my mistake? I try to download 5 times the file but I receive only 1 file. http://collabedit.com/8ysuf  Name: aa